# Can I label my QuantumCircut qubits by something other than integers in Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit

I am learning Qiskit, and I have a specific application in mind where all of the qubits in my QuantumCircit have natural labels (say, by letters of the alphabet). I can initialize this with the code

```
qc = QuantumCircuit(0)

for label in keys:
    qc.add_register(QuantumRegister(1,label))
```

This works and displays very nicely, but immediately gives me problems. For instance, something like

```
qc.x(qubit="label")
```

gives me the error

```
CircuitError: "Invalid bit index: 'label' of type '<class 'str'>'"
```

Is there any way around this? Can I choose the labels I desire for my QuantumCircut, or must I stick with the default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your method to initialize the qubits, but you need to remember their indices to apply gates. One way to do this is to create a dictionary mapping each label to its corresponding index and then use it when applying quantum gates to your circuit. The code would look something like this:

```python
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister 

labels = ['qub1', 'qub2', 'qub3', 'ancilla']
index = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(labels)} # map the labels to their indices

qc = QuantumCircuit()
for label in labels:
    qc.add_register(QuantumRegister(1, label))

x_gates = ['qub1', 'qub3', 'ancilla']

for register in x_gates:
    qc.x(index[register])
    
qc.draw()
```

The circuit will then look like this:

[image]

Be careful though, because not all register names are valid according to the OpenQASM specification!